# Array contents not being passed fully from php client to a .NET web service

Tags: php, asp.net, image, web-services, arrays

I want to pass an image as a byte array from **php** to a .NET web serice. 
The **php** client is as follows:

```
<?php
class Image{
  public $ImgIn = array();
}
$file = file_get_contents('chathura.jpg');
$ImgIn = str_split($file);
foreach ($ImgIn as $key=>$val) { $ImgIn[$key] = ord($val); }

$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:64226/Service1.asmx?wsdl');
$result = $client->PutImage(new Image());
echo $result->PutImageResult;
//print_r($ImgIn);

?>
```

Here is the web method in ASP.NET web service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string PutImage(byte[] ImgIn)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms =
           new System.IO.MemoryStream(ImgIn);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b =
          (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

        b.Save("imageTest", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return "test";
    }
```

When I run this the image content is correctly read to **ImgIm** array in php client. (In this instance the image had 16992 elements.) However when the array is passed to the web service method it contains only 5 elements (the first 5 elements of the image)
Can I know what is the reason for the loss of data ? How can I avoid it ?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing $ImgIn instead of new Image() in the line $result = $client->PutImage(new Image());?

Comment: Have you tried checking what is transmitted over the wire (maybe using Fiddler or a packet sniffer?)

Comment: @Dan: I have declared ImgIn as a property of the Image class. So when I use new Image all its property values are being passed. It is a different way of passing parameters.

@Rowland: I put a breakpoint inside the web method and did debugging. There I noticed that the byte array there contains only 5 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, it seems that it is not going to be any use to try and pass data as a byte array as PHP anyway converts it to a string when sending. This conversion seems to introduce control characters to the string, making it only send a part of the byte array.                      I got this to work by sending a base64 encoded string and decoding inside the server. 
     My client side code:

```
<?php
class Image{
public $ImgIn = '';
}
//ini_set("memory_limit","20M");
$imageData = file_get_contents('chathura.jpg');
$encodedData = base64_encode($imageData);
$Img = new Image();
$Img->ImgIn = $encodedData;
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:64226/Service1.asmx?wsdl');
$result = $client->PutImage($Img);
echo($result->PutImageResult);    
?>
```

ASP .NET web service code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string PutImage(String ImgIn)
    {
        byte[] ImgInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImgIn);
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms =
           new System.IO.MemoryStream(ImgInBytes);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b =
          (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

        b.Save("C:\\imageTest.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return "success";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns the file contents as string which is not useful for binary files such as images. Try this:

```
$handle = fopen("chathura.jpg", "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize("chathura.jpg"));
fclose($handle);
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:64226/Service1.asmx?wsdl');
$result = $client->PutImage($contents);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it does not pass anything to the web service. 
However the method file_get_contents I have used is successful considering the method I have used in web service. But the problem is that the entire array content is not being passed to the web service.

Comment: Your code also worked. But it has the problem I have mentioned. That is not the entire content of the array is being passed. I m thinking it might be due to a limitation in array size in php. Any ideas ?